# Buildozer in Google Colab not creating APK file, need troubleshooting

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I am attempting to use Buildozer in a Google Colab environment to build an APK file for my Kivy app. However, despite following the steps outlined in this guide, I'm encountering an issue where Buildozer fails to execute the last command, and it does not generate the APK file as expected.

I have already tried the following troubleshooting steps:

Set log_level to 2 in my buildozer.spec file for more detailed logs.
Checked for Python errors in my code, which runs without issues locally.
Updated Buildozer to the latest version.
Cleaned the Buildozer build cache.
Ensured a stable internet connection in my Colab environment.
Despite these efforts, I still cannot identify the specific problem causing the build failure. The error message provided is not giving me enough information to pinpoint the issue.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to troubleshoot this problem further or share any potential solutions? Additionally, if you have encountered similar issues with Buildozer in Google Colab, please share your experiences and any insights that could be helpful.

Thank you for your assistance!